# Philippine passport misspelled surname applying for schengen visa using work permit

Tags: visas, schengen, filipino-citizens, malta

I using Philippines passport I renewed it in Kuwait last 2016 but when I go back to the Philippines this 2017 I didn't recognised that my passport has a problem the DFA inform me to renew to correct my surname. What should I do? Can I attach my old passport to the new passport so that the visa know that I just renew because of my surname!

Answer (score 1):

Edit: This answer is based on a misunderstanding of the question. See asker's comment below.

If the new passport has the wrong spelling then your best option is to get the DFA to replace it with a correct version.

When you apply for the Schengen visa, include a note about what happened but only if the work permit (I assume the wp was issued by Kuwait) has a different spelling from your correct legal name.

Your post is hard to read because there are no punctuation marks or new lines. Try to make your application easier to read.

Comment: The old passport has the wrong spelling so the DFA said to renew thats why i renew for the new one but the work permit come from Malta using the old passport  number if im going to apply visa for schengen what should i do do i need to attach the old passport to the new passport?